Advisor won't let me push back against reviewer comments
I am a PhD student at a US institution and I am trying to revise a recent paper that I have submitted, to address some comments we have had from reviewers. I am first author, with my advisor also on the paper; however, my advisor seems to be unhappy with the way I am trying to 'push back' against some of the reviewers' comments. They have told me they think I am being overly aggressive and confrontational in my responses.
To clarify, we have already made substantial changes and clarifications to the paper to address most of the reviewer comments. However, there are a handful of comments (5-10%) which I strongly feel are 'off-base' and need to be pushed back on, for the good of the paper. However, my advisor is taking a position that it is not possible for a reviewer to be wrong and that any attempt to question or push back is unacceptable and would be viewed as offensive.
I don't think I am being rude or aggressive in my responses at all - I am trying to be polite but at the same time objective and factual. I disagree strongly with some of the reviewers' comments, which come across to me in some cases as 'off-base' or even misunderstanding key points of the paper. Incorporating those changes to the paper would either add confusion, distract or in some cases may even undermine the premise of the paper (e.g. based on misunderstandings). So, I feel there is a need to be somewhat robust in our responses and defend our work. However, my advisor seems to be of the opinion that the reviewers are the ultimate authority and their feedback cannot be challenged.
We ultimately seem to have very different opinions on how reviewer responses should be handled (and I feel like this ultimately may come down to a difference of style/approach). My instinct is to stand my ground and mount a robust defense of our work, especially in cases where the comments betray some misconception or are otherwise off-base. However, my advisor seems to want to be extremely deferential to the reviewers, taking the view that their feedback can't be questioned - every comment must be reflected in a change to the paper (even if their comments miss the point or don't make sense).
This paper is very important to me and I have a lot invested in it. I am a couple of months away from defending. This paper will represent a large portion of the thesis I have been working on for the past two years. I am planning to stay in academia and this paper will form an important part of my academic portfolio. However, this situation with my advisor is getting to the point where I feel it is going to cause us to water down and significantly reduce the impact of our work, which I find difficult to accept, having put so much into it.
The situation is causing me a lot of stress and I am finding it difficult to deal with. I would really appreciate some advice/insights from experienced academics who are outside our immediate group, in terms of general thoughts and what is the best way to deal with the situation. Surely there are cases where it is justified to push back against reviewer comments? I'm totally open to the possibility that I'm the one that is in the wrong and/or have the wrong attitude, but I'd very much like to hear some other perspectives.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You seem to be mounting a strong defence (or even a strong offence) against this reviewer (were there other easier ones or just this one for this paper), do you expect to do the same with myriad readers too?

"misunderstanding key points of the paper."
If the reviewer misunderstood key points, then likely many others would misunderstand them, too.  So you need to fix that in the paper.  By all means, explain what the reviewer misunderstood: but do that in an edit of the paper, not in a rebuttal of the review.

Yes, agreed. Keep in mind that the reviewer represents a well-informed audience member. If they don’t understand the point, the average reader will be hopelessly lost.

Thank you for your answer. However, in most cases we are doing exactly this. We have already made a lot of changes to the paper, to clarify things based on the reviewer feedback. However, there are a handful of comments (5-10%) that I strongly feel need to be pushed back on, because they are off-base and accepting them would either add confusion or undermine the premise of the paper. However, my advisor is taking a position that: the reviewers must be right. Their word is as law; every comment must be accepted, without question. To challenge them in any way is to insult them.

@Time4Tea "there are a handful of comments (5-10%) that I strongly feel need to be pushed back on" This is key information that you omitted from the OP and that's leading to skewed answers. Your OP does not at all make it sound like you addressed the vast majority of the referee's comments, hence the answers you are getting. However, if your advisor takes the attitude that every single referee comment must be accepted without question, then they are simply wrong. Fwiw I myself as a referee do not expect (and do not even want) the authors to precisely follow every single one of my comments.

@AdamPřenosil thanks for your input. I will edit the question shortly to clarify.

@Time4Tea If the comments are off-base, then the reviewer got a conclusion different from your intended one. Find why, fix it if a correction needs to be made, and include in the article why the specific concern the referee had does not apply. At the end it's not the referee that you must convince, but every single reader of your paper.

@Neinstein Not "every single reader", just an overwhelming majority.

"If the reviewer misunderstood key points, then likely many others would misunderstand them, too." <- In my limited experience, some reviewers are simply ignorant of the subject matter, regardless of the specific paper submitted, and failures of program committees/editorial boards is what gets such papers to them in the first place. In which case, that statement is untrue, since the readers would be those actually interested/background in the paper's subfield.

@einpoklum: But at least some of your readers are going to be reading because they're interested in the subfield, but not already an expert; or an expert in another subfield trying to learn the minimum of your subfield to get an advancement in their subfield.

@AlexanderThe1st True, but if someone from a different field decides to read an advanced paper in your field out of curiosity, they should not be surprised if there are aspects they do not understand. It’s fine for someone from a different (sub)field not to understand parts of an article without further reading, but it’s also perfectly fine for articles to include such parts. If a limited understanding of the field forms the basis of review comments, then it’s also fine to consider that the target audience will not misunderstand and accordingly not accommodate those comments.

@einpoklum "some reviewers are simply ignorant of the subject matter" the whole point of publishing journal papers is to cure ignorance.  If some reviewers are ignorant of the subject matters, that is likely to be even more the case for the general readership.  When we write papers the intended audience is not just the experts but all readers of the journal that might be interested in the idea.  If you write in a way that is only accessible by experts you are unnecessarily limiting the take up (and citations) of your work.  So even if you think the reviewer is ignorant, use their comments.

@DikranMarsupial: No, that's not the whole point. There are introductory/review articles, and there are articles describing new research findings. (And PhD candidates are more likely to be writing the latter rather than the former.)

@einpoklum I disagree, new research findings ought to be presented in a manner that is accessible for any reader of the journal that would be interested in it.  The point of publishing is to allow others to take up your ideas, so if you prevent that from happening by writing in an obscure manner, you are limiting the value of your work (of course in some cases the obscurity is more a feature than a bug ;o).

Basically, understand: the reviewers stand between you and the publication. After the paper is published, that's it. It's yours.
In other words, "being right" in the discussion with reviewers is not the priority. This discussion is invisible (unless you work with OpenReview). It will disappear into the depths of the past.
What will remain is the message that gets through in the paper.
As a consequence, fighting with reviewers that can prevent you from publishing is not usually a good idea, unless the reviewers are factually wrong and you know exactly how and about what to fight them.
It is more likely that your advisor has experience on the latter and a better judgement on this than you. Therefore, I would suggest that you defer to them on any point that is not crucial. Decide which points absolutely need to be upheld and make the case politely, respectfully and factually. On the rest, I suggest to compromise.
Also, it can help to try to understand why the reviewers misunderstood you. Did you perhaps not write clearly? Was your formulation ambiguous? Maybe you are indeed wrong or could be interpreted in the wrong way?
Try to play advocatus diaboli with yourself and defend the reviewer's point of view. This will give you clarity and it may also lower your resentment against getting things changed, especially if you can identify points where the reviewer may have had a point. Thus it can help you put yourself in their shoes.
That being said, reviewers of course can be wrong, but this should be your very last assumption, when all your other compromise options have failed.
Finally, your advisor seems to see this publication outlet as the outlet of choice and gives an acceptance a high priority.
In short: my recommendation is to insist/push back on the minimum: essentials and objective reviewer mistakes only, and try to understand as much as possible what the reviewers want from you and what your advisor suggests. You are almost finished: you want that paper out.

PhD students often think they have made point x clearly in the paper, but often they have only hinted at x while making some other point. I ask them to show me exactly where they have made point x and they sheepishly realize they cannot find it.

"Basically, understand: the reviewers stand between you and the publication. After the paper is published, that's it. It's yours." And it's important to realise that even if you have to compromise in a paper (often because it only covers a part of your research, you can't develop all your ideas), then going forward you can continue with your approach and ideas, not theirs. Reviewers decide what goes in the publication, and probably know better than you what can and should be published at this time in this way, but they don't rule your life.

" play advocatus diaboli " indeed - I advise my students to write papers the way a chess player plays chess.  Don't play the strongest move you can see, play the move for which your opponents response is the weakest.  Be your own "reviewer #3" before submitting the paper.  Having said which - I have had reviewers write things that are demonstrably incorrect, and I have unequivocally demonstrated it in my response, but the editor sided with the reviewer anyway due to their eminence in the field.  Humans are fallible, and peer review involves humans.

I think there are two things you get wrong:

When a reviewer misunderstands something, then many readers will too. My perspective on reviewer comments is therefore that these are simply my first readers; the place to address their misunderstandings is in the paper, because that's where it originates. Nobody is helped if you mount a strong response with the reviewers because that does not improve the paper. Your goal should be to get the best possible paper out, not to do battle with reviewers.

Advisers are often deferential to reviewers because they have decades of experience in how the system works, and you don't. Your question comes over as saying "I don't need your advice, I know how to do this", but in reality you don't (and can't) because you do not have a long history as a reviewer, editor, or other participant in the publication process.



"Advisers are often deferential to reviewers because they have decades of experience in how the system works": Isn't it just about being friendly and grateful to a person who just put in (potentially a lot) voluntary work into commenting on your paper, leading to an improved revised paper?

To your first point - in most cases we are doing this. We have made a lot of changes to the paper, to clarify things based on the reviewer feedback. However, there are a handful of comments (5-10%) that need to be pushed back on, because they are off-base and accepting them would either add confusion or undermine the premise of the paper. However, my advisor is taking a position that: the reviewers must be right; every comment must be accepted, without question. To challenge them in any way is to insult them.

@Snijderfrey "Isn't it just about being friendly and grateful to a person who just put in voluntary work" - Unfortunately human psychology is more complicated than that. Many reviewers will not be happy with friendliness and gratefulness alone, they have the feeling that they are right and will stick to it and defend it, and will only accept if the authors acknowledge that reviewer is right and change things accordingly, regardless of whether they are really right. I'm not saying that this is good (for science), and I'm not saying they're all like this... but many are.

@Time4Tea As author, I do occasionally challenge reviewers, but I try to avoid it as far as I can. And I do it only if I have good reason to believe that the editor will agree with me, because at the end of the day the editor makes the decisions, not the reviewers, but many editors don't feel confident about the contents of papers they handle, so some (but not all) will just follow the reviewers no matter what. Also it is important whether other reviewers were more positive, potentially even regarding the issues in question.

@ChristianHennig, fair enough. Let's just say that being friendly and showing some gratitude are my reasons to write replies to reviewers the way I do. And I don't refrain at all from letting them know when I disagree, with generally positive outcomes (paper gets published).

@Time4Tea There is a difference between explaining politely to a reviewer why you don't want to do something, and "'push back' against some of the reviewers' comments." If your adviser feels that you are "being overly aggressive and confrontational in my responses", then they might just be right. If your adviser feels that way, a reviewer may too.

In support of @WolfgangBangerth : the issue here is not so much “pushing back” but doing it aggressively.  If you objective is get the paper published, you are unlikely to win over the referee or the editor if your reply is perceived to be aggressive.  Now, your reply may or may not be aggressive as a matter of fact, but if your advisor thinks it is, you have lost an important ally in the process.

See the multiple appendices of this arxiv posting and in particular Appendix 5 page 23 (admittedly an extreme case).

@Time4Tea " because they are off-base and accepting them would either add confusion or undermine the premise of the paper. " if you can't respond to their misunderstanding without adding confusion or undermining the premise, then either there is a potential problem with the premise that you should address or you don't understand the ideas (or their misunderstanding) properly, in which case it suggests your paper is not as clear as it needs to be.  It sounds like it may be useful feedback to me.

@ZeroTheHero If I still taught a CPD module on reviewing, I would be using that as an example!

I once got a referee report that said roughly "I was confused by X, and I think maybe you should do Y and Z here."
Y and Z didn't make any sense. However, I thought about the reviewer's criticism, and tried to imagine why he or she would suggest Y and Z. I decided that this part of my paper was confusing overall, and rewrote it entirely to make the argument clearer.
I then explained these changes in my response to the reviewer. The reviewer was happy, and my paper was accepted.
I'd recommend you consider doing the same: if you don't like the reviewer's suggestions, try to understand their underlying complaints and see if you can think of another way to address them.

Excellent point. I have seen writers refer to this as “understanding the note behind the note.”

You don’t have to do the suggestion. You have to clear up the misunderstanding that led to the suggestion.


They have told me they think I am being overly aggressive and confrontational in my responses.


my advisor seems to want to be extremely deferential to the reviewers, taking the view that their feedback can't be questioned

What your advisor is telling you sounds sensible. What you are inferring your advisor wants doesn't.
It doesn't seem fair that you use your assumption to guide what you do and how you think about your advisor rather than what they are actually telling you.
Some deference to reviewers is traditional because they are in fact in a decision-influencing role with respect to your paper.
I'd recommend working with your advisor to figure out how best to communicate and also to sort through what is negotiable and non-negotiable.

I would rephrase "Some deference to reviewers is traditional because they are in fact in a decision-influencing role with respect to your paper." into "Some deference to reviewers is appropriate because they have decades of experience and you don't."

@WolfgangBangerth "decades of experience" is not a prerequisite for being a paper reviewer in any of the domains I’ve worked in.

@WolfgangBangerth Surely depends on the field, but I was asked to review papers after I published my first one.  Which where the results of my master thesis, so I wasn't even a PhD student.

I can certainly understand 'some' deference to reviewers being wise and reasonable. However, total deference to them, to the extent that their word should be treated as law and it should be considered an offense to question or challenge them, in any way? This is the position my advisor seems to be taking.

You don't need to be confrontational to defend your point of view. Try seeing reviewers as your friends, not as an obstacle on the way to publication. After all, you want to publish a paper that you will be proud of even 10-20 years later, and both you and your reviewers have the same goal -- to improve the paper. Try to collaborate with them in the same way as with your co-authors. Frankly, in my career I had much more trouble convincing co-authors than convincing the reviewers. ;-)

@Time4Tea As others have pointed out, you keep relying on this "seems to be" language that lets you ascribe any motive you imagine to your advisor. You should focus instead on what they are actually telling you, not what you imagine or what "seems". Your shared goal should be to get the paper published.

Perhaps it would help if you tell us how young your advisor is. If he is very young (e.g. assistant professor on tenure track), he might still naively think that reviewers are more experienced than him. For a more senior advisor, I would really struggle to understand why he would assume that his opinion matters less than that of a random reviewer. Sounds like he has some kind of inferiority complex. Usually graduate students look up to reviewers as gods, and eminent scientists argue with them about anything, not the other way around.

@Vosoni my advisor is relatively young - on tenure track.

You see -- I could guess that.

+1 "Some deference to reviewers is traditional" also because they are offering their time and energy for free when you would not be able to afford it at their consulting rates!  A good reviewer is trying to help you, and that should not be rewarded by hostility/disrespect.  The golden rule should apply, how would you want authors to respond to your reviews?


Surely there are cases where it is justified to push back against reviewer comments?

Yes, of course. However, it makes a lot of sense to think how to to this without being too confontational. Reviewers sometimes miss a point in a paper they assess, and that may reflect in some of their comments. So how can you and the paper still benefit from that? It is certainly no help to write an "angry" reply to the reviewers, rather assume they are trying to help. Then, it is your job as an author to find that aspect in the reviewer reply which helps you to improve your paper.
There is nothing wrong to explain in the response to the reviewers that you believe a reviewer misunderstood something. At the same time, think why this has happened and what you can do from your side to avoid this from happening to other future readers. And of course revise your paper accordingly.
This way, it should be easy for you to frame your response to the reviewers in a positive way because without their comments and the thoughts they provoked, indeed your paper would be a less good paper. You can be grateful for that, can't you? This has nothing to do with being overly deferential to the reviewers. It is more about showing a positive attitude towards their comments and the effort they put into looking through the paper. Rather than saying "I am right and you are wrong", you may say "I am right and you helped me to make my point clearer. Thank you for that".

Perhaps there is a difference in perception between me and my advisor, but I really don't think I am being too confrontational or aggressive in my responses. I am being polite, objective and factually accurate. However, my advisor is taking the view that everything the reviewers have said must be right, and must be accepted, without question. To question or attempt to correct them is to insult.

@Time4Tea, assuming what you say is true, then my view is that your advisor is wrong. As a self-confident researcher, it is important to be able to judge when to defend your work, and when to accept reasonable criticism, even if it comes in the disguise of an odd reviewer comment. If it is smart to go into dispute with your advisor about this is a totally different question.

The advisor is actually the first person a PhD student should dispute with. To a grad student he is supposed to be like a punching bag to a boxer. The ability to argue and support a scientific dispute is the central skill a scientist is supposed to have, and being OK with someone having a different opinion is part of that culture. So it really makes a difference if the advisor can be argued with without feeling insulted. If he puts authority above the strength of logical argument, he is not a very good supervisor to start with. So you need to decide if it is possible to convince him.

@Vosoni right, my understanding is that as researchers, we are supposed to be able to defend our work. So ... "let me do it then!". I thought that a thesis defense is called that for a reason - not just a name. Isn't the point of a PhD program to develop strong, independent thinkers, who can conduct a scientific debate, rather than cowering subservients?

Just be careful, because if neither you nor your advisor have mastered the art of the dispute, it can end in a bitter divorse. But from what you wrote, your attitude appears very reasonable to me. I had similar conflicts with my supervisor during my PhD time, and I survived. ;-)

I acted more than a hundred times either as author or as reviewer, and I also have the "Outstanding Referee" status from the American Physical Society. From my experience, I can tell you that reviewers do make mistakes. They can be less experienced than the authors (very often the case), or they can simply lack time or motivation to read the paper carefully. Therefore what the reviewers write is certainly not the law. Objectively, their opinion has approximately the same weight (in my eyes perhaps even smaller weight) than that of the authors. Assuming that we are talking about some high-quality paper with several distinguished and experienced team members on the author list, the authors have normally spent months if not years polishing every detail, and they know their topic way better than an external referee who has spent at best a few hours (often just 15 minutes) to write their report. There are, of course, quite opposite situations, but I am now talking about a healthy, mutually beneficial author-reviewer relationship. It is totally OK to point the reviewer's attention to a possible mistake or omission, as long as this is done with due respect. You should not neglect your reviewers, every point they raised should be addressed. Every change you agree with or find neutral (will do no harm) is better accepted than argued against. However, if you think the reviewer proposed something that will make your paper worse, I would argue in the reply why that shouldn't be done. In 90% of the cases the reviewer would see your point and simply agree. After all, it's a dialogue between you and the reviewers, and you typically have 2-3 rounds. If you see a way to improve the explanations so that similar misunderstandings do not occur after the paper is published, do it. However, reviewers sometimes overlook even what is explicitly written. A good review is usually seen by the authors as helpful in improving the manuscript. If that's not the case, your reviewer is probably not so good or experienced, after all.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


However, my advisor seems to want to be extremely deferential to the reviewers, taking the view that their feedback can't be questioned - every comment must be reflected in a change to the paper (even if their comments miss the point or don't make sense).

(Emphasis mine)
If (if) this is accurate, then your advisor is off base. I was going to say "wildly offbase" but that isn't true. Deference to reviewers is usually wise because although the final decision belongs to the editor, the editor almost certainly trusts the reviewers.
Even so, subservience to every whim of the reviewers is not good.  Reviewers can be unreasonable and obstreperous, too.
However:

my advisor seems to be unhappy with the way I am trying to 'push back' against some of the reviewers' comments. They have told me they think I am being overly aggressive and confrontational in my responses.

(Emphasis mine)
This, however, is not the same thing.  Please understand that this is a separate issue from excessive deference to the reviewer.
But moreover, there's a lot of reliance on "seems" in your text.  I've highlighted only half your usage.  You need to actually understand where your advisor stands on the reviewer comments.  I've submitted papers my advisor and I thought were ready at the time, and gotten them back with comments that convinced him (and me) that we had more work to do.  This may be the case; your advisor may consider the comments valid.  Or some other factors may be at play.
But you're not going to get any satisfaction or make much headway until you can rewrite it without "seems" or anything similar.

My usage of the word 'seems' stems from a desire to comment on how I see things from my perspective/point-of-view. Which is all I can really comment on. I wouldn't try to represent my point-of-view as fact. You could replace the word 'seems' with 'from my point-of-view'.

@Time4Tea You are missing the point.  You have to talk to your advisor about this until you no longer need to hedge about this.

"Reviewers can be unreasonable and obstreperous, too." Don't I know it. I had a reviewer that kept nitpicking small formatting details which were nothing to do with the content of the paper. I was happy to make some changes initially, but after the third round I was getting sick of their gripes and chose to ignore all of their formatting comments.

You already got a lot of great answers; I'd just extend them with an advise instead.
Learn to disagree with agreeing.
I actually agree with your supervisor, without knowing context. You can, and have to, always assume that the reviewer is a highly regarded expert of the specific field you are publishing in. Correspondingly, a) whatever concern they raised is valid, and b) the same doubt would likely be raised in the head of other readers - especially other experts, whose attention you want to grasp the most. Considering this, the best course is to always make corrections based on each of the reviewer's comment.
Now - the question is how to carry these corrections out.

Suppose the reviewer stated something as incorrect, while you're confident it is. Perhaps the statement is not as convincing as you thought? Include a few citation-doped sentences providing strong support for that claim.
The reviewer believes something you did shouldn't be done that way, but you disagree? Then extend the article with a paragraph as strong as you can that shows why it is actually a good approach, including why each of the specific potential issues raised by the reviewer do not apply in your case. Best if you can cite other works applying a similar approach. Do so even if your reasons seem obvious or irrelevant - it didn't seem so for at least one good reader of yours.
The reviewer marks something as irrelevant or out of the scope of the paper, but you don't think so? Seems you didn't explain well enough why it's relevant, or the flow is not correct. Add a few sentences specifically explaining the relevance, and make sure that the marked content is referred to in multiple non-unimportant places of the manuscript.
The reviewer wrote something utter nonsense or irrelevant? Figure where the reviewer got the wrong ideas from, rephrase the corresponding part, and agree that the section was phrased poorly, expressing gratitude for pointing that out.

Your supervisor is right - you should never* just disagree* with the reviewer. But that just means you shouldn't deny considering their comment. You're free to not agree
And the last but IMO most vital point: if your revision didn't convince even your own supervisor, you can safely assume it won't work on the reviewer either.

* Except very rare cases, that should never happen ideally, where the reviewer is completely and blatantly wrong, like stating that the Earth is flat.

In my experience, reviewers who are blatantly wrong are not as rare as you suggest. It depends on the impact factor of the journal, of course, but sometimes I want to bang my head against the wall when I read the reviews. I mean not only reviews of my papers, but also other reviews of the papers I review.

@Vosoni I agree and have encountered at least one such reviewer myself, not even in a low-impact journal. But even in that case, I believe this method is the safest to follow. Take action on every comment, even if the action is a simple rephrasing of one sentence, agree that something may be confusing, thank for the comment, and move on. But ideally, in such cases, the incompetence should be obvious to the editor anyway.

But why do you need the safest method? There are many ways to fight against bad reviewers. One can ask the editor to seek one more review, one can even abandon that journal and submit elsewhere. The problem here is those decisions must be taken by the supervisor, who must be daring enough and have self-confidence to protect his own viewpoint and stand on the side of his PhD student. I know a situation when a paper was rejected from a journal and after that published in "Science". Initially the authors didn't dare to submit it to "Science", but the rejection helped.

@Vosoni simply because it is the safest. You want to publish, the reviewer is between you and your goal, the best course of action is to satisfy them. I don't see a reason not to, unless the reviewer asks for such a major refractor that the publication would change significantly in a direction you're not comfortable with. But in such case it's clear that a refusal will result in a rejection, and by doing so, you already decided to submit elsewhere. I think cases where not rephrasing a few paragraphs and figures worths changing to a new journal and restarting the publication process are rare.

@Vosoni When a reviewer doesn't have a clue what they're talking about, the whole review will be blatantly wrong. That should typically be caught by the editor, but if it isn't, it is reasonable to push back against such a review. However, if 90% of the comments make perfect sense, the reviewer has demonstrated the necessary baseline understanding, and if the remaining 10% of their comments are "wrong", it must be because the paper is unclear/too verbose/overreaching/lacking relevant introduction and it's the manuscript that needs fixing, not the review.

Something to bear in mind is that different scholarly communities have different levels of tolerance for push-back in review responses. Having published in a few fields (from water resources engineering to marine biology) the difference can be quite remarkable. So until you have published enough to know the culture of your field, trust your advisor or other experienced coauthors rather than advice from people in other fields on the internet.

This happened to me recently as well. A reviewer disagrees with the fundamental approach we took and no matter how we explain our motivations to them, they cannot accept it. We started with a fairly neutral response and simply trying to convince the reviewer that our work has its own merit. And after the revised paper come back the third time, our responses become more annoyed and so are the reviewer's responses back to us. At the end of the day, the reviewer stated that they will no longer review any more versions of this paper from us.
In my experience, this process highly depends on the editor. Some editor will see that all other reviewers are happy with our revised text, but this editor will try to please all reviewers and held on to the one reviewer's decision and won't accept the paper for publication.
In general, addressing the reviewer's concerns is better than giving a rebuttal. Your advisor is likely speaking from their experience that being overly aggressive by writing rebuttals may turn the reviewers fully against you and result in what happened to me. By being as neutral as possible, you can avoid that scenario and focus on addressing the reviewer's concerns. Instead of rebuttal, you discuss the issue at hand with the reviewer. But that also means sometimes you simply cannot convince the reviewer and if the editor won't make a decision in your favor, the best course of action is to resubmit to a different journal.

I'm pretty sure that your advisor didn't tell you that everything the reviewers have said must be right. This is probably only your understanding of what your advisor wants from you. Most probably the advisor told you that everything the reviewers have said must be addressed by changes in the paper. That's a completely different thing. And I agree with the latter 100%.
You do not leave reviewers comments unanswered and you do not push back. You try the hardest to understand what the reviewer meant and then make a change in the manuscript. This change might not be the thing the reviewer wanted, but you still make a change. You do not address comments by copy-pasting. The comments are for you to improve the manuscript, which means you need to be creative. An off-base comment signifies that the reviewer didn't get something right. So you need to change the text in a way that on next reading your reviewer would understand correctly.
You might think that the reviewer didn't understand because he's not an expert. That might be true. But not all your readers will be experts either. Please don't write articles that are understandable only to experts. Science is already so fragmented and specialized.
You can think of it also this way: the reviewers you got were selected by the editor. These are already the experts. If it's not understandable to them then you wrote your article for super-experts, i.e. you yourself, and maybe your advisor.
You say that you already applied 90% of the reviewers' suggestions. These were the easy ones. Now, for the next 10%, which are off-base, the uphill struggle begins. How do you apply comments that you disagree with? How do you apply comments that you don't even understand? That's precisely your task! And if you want to stay in academia you better learn that skill.
I'd say that pushing back is acceptable maybe on 0.2% of comments. Once every few papers. On very specific occasions that cannot be addressed in any different way. For instance the reviewer wants you to cite a completely irrelevant article that has nothing to do with your work (when they want you to cite something that is just tangentially relevant, then you do cite it). Then you can politely explain your decision, trying to figure out in good faith why the reviewer requested that in the first place. So the push back should actually acknowledge that you understand the request, but still disagree and cannot address it in any meaningful way.
On the other hand, you may find that even in such cases there's still something you can improve in your manuscript. Maybe you don't cite the requested paper, but you do cite a generic paper on field X and explain that your work is based in field Y that is only superficially similar to X. If the reviewer wanted you to cite something about X it might mean that such a disclaimer is actually useful.

When you're writing about complicated subjects, presenting information that is new to your audience, it's best to turn off your ego.
Words are a tool, not a product. Getting fond of particular arrangements of them is counterproductive when you're dealing with difficult material. What matters is getting the ideas across. If the reviewer doesn't understand you, although they have more experience in the field than you, that's a clear signal that you aren't writing clearly.
Your adviser seems to be treating this paper as a training exercise for you, which is entirely reasonable. Your job is to make the paper clear. It would be wise to try out the revised version on someone in your department before you send it back for re-review. Anything they don't understand is a problem you need to fix.
